# Nested blockquotes in Draft JS

Tags: draftjs

I'm curious if it's possible to nest `blockquote` in draft js?  At the moment I'm using `convertFromHTML` to convert a series of nested `blockquote` tags into `ContentState` but it seems only the first `blockquote` is being counted.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can nest inline styles but you might have to provide your own blockRenderMap to do so. Check out the [LaTex example](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/tree/master/examples/tex), and [draft-js-plugins](https://github.com/draft-js-plugins/draft-js-plugins)

Answer (score 0):

In draft js the blockquote is a BlockType and block cannot nest block so you cannot approach it.

But you can use custom inline-style or custom block to simulate it. Inline style can nest and you can make some text `display: 'block'; borderLeft: 2px solid #ccc;` through draft js decorator. And you can create a react component that can receive a tree like data and render as a nested blockquote, use it as a custom block will also approach your goal.

Blockquote is block type element in HTML, generally block don't nest block element so I wonder what content need nest blockquote?